# Bootstrap 4 Form HTML Popover

Tags: jquery, forms, bootstrap-4, popover

Trying to upgrade from Bootstrap 3.
Previously I had a form inside some popovers which is now broken with an empty content. I cannot work out what has changed that breaks this.
The form is demonstrated dynamically, however this can be replicated simply.

HTML:

```
<a id="workingpopovertest" data-toggle="popover">
    <button>Test</button>
</a>
<br /><br /><br /><br />&nbsp;
<a id="brokenpopovertest" data-toggle="popover">
    <button>Test</button>&nbsp;
</a>
```

Script:

```
    $("#brokenpopovertest").popover({
        html: true,
        title: "Broken Popover",
        animation: true,
        content: "<form>Input<input type='text' /></form>",
        container: "body"
    });
    $("#workingpopovertest").popover({
        html: true,
        title: "Working Popover",
        animation: true,
        content: '<h1>I Work Well</h1>',
        container: "body"
    });
```

Giving this result (as expected from the element naming !!

[image]

**Edit Added**

This is with:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what jquery version are you loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are searching for [`sanitize`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/#options) option

[**MORE INFO**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer)

```js
$("#brokenpopovertest").popover({
  html: true,
  title: "Broken Popover",
  animation: true,
  sanitize: false,
  content: "<form>Input<input type='text' /></form>",
  container: "body"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a id="brokenpopovertest" data-toggle="popover">
  <button>Test</button>&nbsp;
</a>
```

Comment: Please could you explain the sanitize option, the documentation is very sketchy and does not actually state what this process does. The additional option does work but need to know its effect to be sure this is the answer (and for future viewers)

Comment: To be honest, I m not aware much about that. As far as I know it's for security purposes

Comment: re TBH: Accepted answer anyway !! hopefully someone else can comment on the sanitize option. It certainly should be called the sanity option !!! I guess there is a popover process that checks markup or something and removes elements for whatever reason - so far it does not make sense